# JDBC versus Webservice for DB connection in mobile apps

Tags: java, android, mysql, web-services, jdbc

I am currently developing an android app and I am going to use MYSQL so the app can upload and download information. Basically, the app has a secure login process. In order to login, the user must create an account, which consists of username, email, password. Then users can upload and download both text and pictures to and from the server.

What are the pros and cons of using JDBC and a Webservice to connect to a DB in a mobile app? What are the differences between them?

Off the top of my head, my two main concerns are which one is better for efficiency (time and bandwidth) and security?

Answer (score 2):

Never use a JDBC connection from a remote device to connect to a database on your server! It is way to insecure because you have no real means to control the statements sent to your database server.

I also wouldn't ever expose a database server directly to the internet to accept JDBC connections, be it from mobile devices or regular desktop applications.

EDIT:

This is a response to the comments below:

Who says just mobile apps can connect? Use a packet sniffer to find out connection parameters for the JDBC connections, and you can connect from the command line. Then you can send whatever SQL-statement you want. You could try attacking the database to gain admin access, you could try querying the database's metadata (tables, columns and so on), then use that information to steal other users login data...

If you have a webservice in between, that too can be attacked, but there is no way to directly attack your database.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly the security issue here is? If all mobile app accounts can only read / write to very specific tables, and no mobile account has admin access, how is this different than using a webservice to do the same procedure?

Comment: You say the webservice can be attacked, but there is no way to directly attack the database. Is this true? Currently, my JSP page and my database share the same IP, but just run on different ports. This might be wrong practice (if so, then the company I am working at is slacking), but in my situation, attacking the webservice is the same thing as attacking the database.

Comment: Normally, I'd block all remote access to the database port using a firewall rule. It should only accept connections from localhost or from within the same network. Same is true for most ports with the exception of 80 (HTTP), 443 (HTTPS), and 22 (SSH). I'd also not run an FTP server and use SCP instead (over SSH port 22).

Comment: Remote access needs to be enabled because the company has offices in different cities that need to access this DB. Under these given circumstances, what noticeable difference is there between using JDBC and a webservice? A person can sniff packets from both and know the destination IP - which is the same for both the Database and Web App. What I don't understand is why I can't just encrypt the data sent from the android phone and compare it with the data in the DB.

Comment: If it's a big company they sure will have a VPN so it will be considered as coming from the same network. If not, I'd rather not have sensible data in that database.

Comment: It's not the IP that's so important. It's the database login parameters. I think it's much harder to set up a secure publicly remote accessible database than securing your web service.